# laravel redirection to localhost after slash in the end of URL

Tags: php, dynamic, laravel-4, routes

i am using laravel 4 in my admin section its working fine in normal condition but when i enter  the path with slash in last like this
    localhost/project_name/public/admin/

than this redirect to

```
localhost/admin
```

and when i remove the  slash from end like this

```
localhost/project_name/public/admin/
```

than its working fine can any body tell the solution for this

and in my routes.php

```
 Route::group(array('prefix'=>'admin','before'=>'admin-auth',), function(){

 Route::get('/','AdminController@index');
```

Comment: Because `localhost/project_name/public/admin/` is wrong. You're referencing a directory not a Laravel path.

Comment: i did not understand can you tell me the solution for this so that if i enter this URL than do not redirect to localhost/admin

Comment: You either set a virtual server for local development or Google `how to set up Laravel on a shared hosting`

Comment: I tried but in my one project its woorking prefectly but in this its showing this kind of error

Comment: Again, Laravel needs to load `index.php` on the `public` directory to resolve the URL you're requesting. Without a `VirtualHost` that explicitly redirects every request to `/path/to/laravel/public` you're not going to get any result. In you case you're trying to access the admin **directory** not the admin **route**.

Comment: than why its working in my another project

Comment: I don't know what you did or you didn't on your other project. I'm just telling you why Laravel can't be simply uploaded to `/var/www` and expect it to work.